# What are some of the most successful redistribution policies used by governments?

Tags: macroeconomics

I was wondering what are the different general types of redistribution policies and which ones have been most successful?

In my economics classes, we learned how important redistribution is to reduce wealth inequality (e.g. as measured by the Gini coefficient), but we didn't really discuss specifics about what strategies governments use in the real world, so I was curious.

Comment: Most successful according to what metric?

Comment: Btw there are multiple GINI measures. Redistribution doesn’t decrease all of them. For example, GINI for income is often reported for market incomes which are pre-tax and pre-transfer, there is not much evidence redistribution can affect that